# Does iPhone support cell broadcasting?

Tags: iphone, ios, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, broadcasting

Does iPhone suppots cell broadcasting

if yes: How to enable it 
if no: is there any way to manually create some method or any predefined api through which we can be able to receive broadcasting messages by service prvider  :)

Answer (score 0):

By default Cell Broadcasting is available on iPhone. You need not to on or off it.

Comment: i mean to say programmatically can i use broadcasting function ?